# Trying to get SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as c# variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-webpages

I am inserting a row into one table then want to get that new ID so I can add it in another variable where I have email address stored.

```
 var db = Database.Open("myDB");
 var insertCommand1 = "INSERT INTO myDB (FirstName, LastName) Values(@0, @1)";                       
 db.Execute(insertCommand1, first, last);
 var lastInsertedId = db.QueryValue("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

 var insertCommand2 = "INSERT INTO email (id_person, email) Values(@0, @1)";
 db.Execute(insertCommand2, lastInsertId, email);
```

where id_person is the id that is created in my first table. When I run the code I get lastInsertedId = {}. Any reason why it is not grabbing a value for id_person which is a primary key, int , not null for my first table? --Tim

Comment: What is `Database`? What does `Execute`, `QueryValue`? You cant get correct value because your statements executed in deffernt scope.

Comment: Instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` try `output inserted.Id` (or whatever the name of the Id column on your person table is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), emphasis mine:

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. **Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch**.

Because you are using two queries they are considered two batches. You need to do your insert and your select in a single query.

I don't know what library you are using, so I am just guessing on the syntax but I beleive you need something like

```
 var db = Database.Open("myDB");
 var insertCommand1 = "INSERT INTO myDB (FirstName, LastName) Values(@0, @1); " +
                      "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
 var lastInsertedId = db.QueryValue(insertCommand1, first, last);

 var insertCommand2 = "INSERT INTO email (id_person, email) Values(@0, @1)";
 db.Execute(insertCommand2, lastInsertId, email);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. clearly explained why it wasn't working and after adding the Select scope_identity to the first query it works fine. I can now follow that query up with others to post to my various other tables, adding my 'lastInsertedId' as a foreign key in the other tables. --Tim

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value back from SQL Server. I will give an example where I was able to print the SCOPE_IDENTITY() data back in c# label.

- My Code Snippet in a Submit from data insert

```
btnSubmit_Click()
{
    Random s = new Random();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMemberAccount] ([Userid], [User_pwd], [User_mobile], [User_referal], [UserWallet]) VALUES(@Userid, @User_pwd, @User_mobile, @User_referal, @UserWallet) ​select scope_identity()", cons); 

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid",s.Next(4506,9999));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_pwd",txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_mobile",txtPhoneNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_referal",txtReferral.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserWallet",10);
    cons.Open();
    int g = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    cons.Close();
    lblConfirm.Text = "Member " +g+ " added successfully!";
}
```

---

Here the value 'g' is returning the scope_identity value.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is in SQL SERVER , create a SQL parameter and set the direction to 
"Output". 
Please check this link :

[Getting the identity of the most recently added record](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)